# alias domain in htaccess and wp-config.php

Tags: redirect

i have did domain alias in htaccess and wp-config.php.
my question is: Can Google penalize my domains because of duplicate content?
and may that affect seo and website rank?
or is this ok to have two alias domains on one website?

wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

.htaccess :

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
<filesmatch ".(eot|font.css|otf|ttc|ttf|woff|jpg|jpeg)$"="">
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
```

for check websites:
**main:** [gymarket.ir](https://gymarket.ir) **alternive:** [gymarket.top](https://gymarket.top)

both of them use public html folder but not redirected.